# How do I set certain system properties with the Azure IoT C SDK for the AMQP protocol and where do they end up in the EventHub?

Tags: c#, c, iot, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

edit: Add more information, see end

In the C# IoT SDK, I can set certain properties on the [message class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.message). There are no equivalent options at [Message Handles](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/inc/iothub_message.h) in the C SDK, however.

How can I set the following properties with the C SDK:

- To
- UserId

Furthermore, how do I access them on the receiver side in C# via the EventData Class and the C SDK with the EventData Class? In the C# class the message properties are split in system properties and properties, whereas in the C class there are only properties. I can only set these properties in the property map when I use the C IoT Hub.

I can't seem to find entries for the following keys in the system properties map:

- "user-id"
- "to"

I can find them in the normal property map, however. When I set them in the C# SDK with the specialized setters, they should appear in the system properties map.

Why does this happen and how can I get this working for both cases? And what are the actual mappings between the C# message class setters and the EventHub system properties and properties?

edit:

Maybe I should be somewhat more specific. I am using the AMQP protocol and according to the standard page 74-78 (Sorry I cannot post a link, due to missing reputation) a message contains "properties", i.e. the properties I can set with SetCorrelationId, and "application properties", which are the properties I can set with the Map_AddOrUpdate method.

I would expect the following:

When receiving the message with the EventHub I expected to have the fields "to" and "user-id" in the system properties map, since those are the names mentioned in the standard. By debugging I was able to see entries in the system properties map which were semantically what I expected, but under different names.

Since that means the properties are probably send, there must be some sort of mapping which corresponds to:

1. AMQP standard property name <-> Eventhub system property name
2. C SDK "system properties" name (automatically inferred or not) <-> Eventhub system properties name

Comment: Do you use Event Hub-compatible endpoint of Azure IoT Hub to receive Device-To-Cloud messages in receiver side?

Comment: I do believe so. I call
eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, iotHubD2cEndpoint);

where 

iotHubD2cEndpoint =  "messages/events"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2017.03.07:

At the current point in time it seems to be a bug / mismatch between the IoT Hub documentation, the AMQP specification, the C and the C# SDK. See [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/111).

For a workaround look at @RitaHan-MSFT's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference [official sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_amqp/iothub_client_sample_amqp.c) of C SDK and set the properties like this:

```
                        static char UseridText[15] = "userid prop";
                        static char propUserid[10] = "user-id";
                        static char toText[10] = "to prop";
                        static char propTo[10] = "to";
                        if (Map_AddOrUpdate(propMap, propTo, toText) != MAP_OK)
                        {
                            (void)printf("ERROR: Map_AddOrUpdate Failed!\r\n");
                        }
                        if (Map_AddOrUpdate(propMap, propUserid, UseridText) != MAP_OK)
                        {
                            (void)printf("ERROR: Map_AddOrUpdate Failed!\r\n");
                        }
```

And access them on the receiver side in C# via the EventData Class like the following code piece. For complete sample of using compatible endpoint to read device-to-cloud messages you can reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted#receive-device-to-cloud-messages).

```
            if (eventData.Properties.ContainsKey("to"))
            {
                object value;
                eventData.Properties.TryGetValue("to", out value);
                Console.WriteLine("property key: 'to' value: '{0}'", value.ToString());
            }
            if (eventData.Properties.ContainsKey("user-id"))
            {
                object value;
                eventData.Properties.TryGetValue("user-id", out value);
                Console.WriteLine("property key: 'user-id' value: '{0}'", value.ToString());
            }
```

As for accessing them on the receiver side in C SDK with the EventData Class you can use `EventData_Properties()`. This is the [receive sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-c/blob/b1b28676ee228c6cf828a4cb3f2505d65c3284a9/eventhub_client/samples/receive/receive.c#L79) you can reference.

Comment: But wouldn't that only put an entry into the map 'Properties', which is also a system property?

Comment: That is, instead of assigning the value to a system property, you suggest creating a custom mapping using a string that is equal to the documented name of that property.

Comment: Sadly, this is not quite what I'm looking for although it is a valid work around. I am tempted to accept this due to it's practicality, but I have provided more information about the issue in my original question.

Comment: System properties, both for [azure iot hub message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#message-format) and [event hub event data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.systemproperties?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData_SystemProperties) are predetermined and can't be able to set by user.

Comment: I see. I find it strange, however, that the .NET SDK Message allows setting them. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.message.to?view=azuredevicesclient-1.2.6#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_Message_To) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.message.userid?view=azuredevicesclient-1.2.6#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_Message_UserId).

From your references, I still don't know if D2C messages have or can set a UserId. It only mentions the value set for C2D messages.

Comment: My reference ([message format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#message-format)) is a common message format that supports multiple device-facing protocols (such as MQTT, AMQP, and HTTP). It looks like the possible reason. You propose a good question. These documents actually confused me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. These documents also confused me.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT That is why I'm so confused about which entries can be set, are actually set and must be set. There seem to be a couple of inconsistencies between the SDKs and the documentation. I think circumventing the problem via the application properties can work, however.